# Vertex AI Vision App Undeployment Fails because of state error

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

I build a Vertex AI Vision App via the interface and deployed it. As it was just for testing I want to undeploy and delete it now but I always get the following error when I try to undeploy it:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzfGN.png)

I tried to undeploy it via the interface where I got the error message and I also tried it via cloud shell but it doesn't work there either. Does anyone have experience with the states of these apps and how I can successfully undeploy this app?